# DAO connection to Access .accdb database using Python

Tags: python

I’m having an issue with one of my Python apps that has been working fine with an older .mdb Access Databases. After converting to Access 2010 and the file being converted to the new .accdb format nothing seems to be working. I do have the 32 bit Access version loaded on a new 64 bit Win 7 OS.  I believe my problem is with the first two lines of my code. I believe I need to update them to reference the "Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object" but I’m unclear how to do this. Can I get some help on this one? I have searched high and low for DAO info regarding this scenario but to avail.

```
 import win32com.client
 engine = win32com.client.Dispatch("DAO.DBEngine.36")

 db=engine.OpenDatabase(r"c:\temp\Tracker.accdb")

 table = db.OpenRecordset("select * from Event_Log")
 print table.RecordCount
```

Answer (score 4):

An answer probably too late for the OP, but in case anyone else stumbles in here looking for an answers in the area of DAO with Python:

The OP is correct that the immediate issue lies with the string used in the Dispatch method. Office 2010 (Office 14?) installs "DAO.DBEngine.120", which is I think the earliest version that works with .accdb files.  In general, one can research this issue by using RegEdit to search the registry for the substring "DAO.DBEngine", and see what components have been registered that add a version number to that string.

It should also be noted that the 32/64 bitness of the version of python to be used needs to match the 32/64 bitness of the DAO version, which in turn matches the 32/64 bitness of Office that installed it.

A further note: If you are using an IDE and make use of autocomplete, it's useful to generate and import a module corresponding to the DAO API.  This can be done by running the MakePy utility (in the PythonWin program) on the Library in question, here "Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library". This produces a module file in site-packages\win32com\gen_py\, with a long GUID name... you can rename it to "DAO_120-64.py" or somesuch. Then add the gen_py directory to the Python path (or add a .pth file in sitepackages), so that import can find the new module.

Once imported, you can do whatever your IDE recognizes to associate a type with variables for DAO.Database, DAO.Recordset, and so on.

Additionally, the generated DAO module is a useful reference for what objects, methods, properties and constants are available. Possibly a more helpful reference is to simply open an Excel/Word/Access VBA project, Reference (import) this same library, and use the VBA Object browser on it.

In general, any tutorials or articles about using DAO in Access (in VBA or VB) will describe the objects, methods and properties involved in common operations, which can be transcribed almost verbatim into python. The main difference is that in the python version, some of the COM "default method" mechanisms don't work. So, for example, the VBA

MyRecordset("SomeColumn") = "NewValue"

... corresponds in python to:

MyRecordset.Fields("SomeColumn").Value = "NewValue"

Hope that helps.